# npm install -g typescript npm ERR! errno -13

Tags: angular, linux, typescript

[error npm 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLTCK.png)

install typescript-g
When I want to install the script, I encounter a problem

errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/tsc'

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?more_on=xron.net). People here regard that as evil. Post the actual code, so whoever is willing to help can copy it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's never a good idea to install TypeScript globally. One solution would be to install typescript to the local package:

```
$ npm init
// Run the above if you don't have a package.json
// (you can press enter for each to accept defaults)

$ npm install -D typescript
// install typescript as a dev dependency for your package
// as TypeScript is not a prod dependency.
```

Then you can add this in your package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "create-tsconfig": "tsc --init"
  }
}
```

Finally, run `npm run create-tsconfig` and you will get a tsconfig.json where you can configure how TypeScript works for your project.